# Smartface adding buttons that navigate to another page in the app

Tags: jquery, smartface.io

I tried adding buttons that redrict to certain pages however every time I change one button it changes all the other buttons as to where the page would navigate.
This is what happens...
 [what the script editor shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqUXN.png)
 [what happens to other buttons when I change just one button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a97Ht.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The show() method needs some parameters to work.
You could try something like this:
Pages.Page2.show(4, 2, 1, false, false);

If you want to check on these parameters, go to Smartface API (http://docs.smartface.io/) and find the Page section (SMF.UI.Page), from there, find the show() method and you will see a list of it's parameters.

Hope that helps :)

**Edit**

Full tutorial:

1. Create a Text Button and name it whatever you want (the button name doesn't need to be the same as the label inside it). **Image 1**
2. Go to the script editor and choose the "OnPressed" event of the created button in the upper bar (it'll be the button name). **Image 2**
3. It'll create a code in the editor automatically, now just add the Pages.[putThePageNameHere].show(4, 2, 1, false, false); inside this automatically-generated function and thats it. **Image 3**

Image 1
[image: 1]]

Image2
[image: 2]]

Image 3
[image: 3]]

Again, hope that helps :)

Comment: Sorry, I tried that but It didn't work I'm grateful for your answer

Comment: Have you ever used buttons in an app

Comment: If so, please may you copy the whole source code in the script editor of one of the buttons so that I can check if the code works on the buttons on my app.

Comment: Thankyou I'm really grateful

Comment: Of course! I will edit the answer because a comment is less organized :)

Comment: You're welcome! Always glad to help! :) But if the question is answered, mark it to help others know that they don't need to look into it anymore.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add Pages.Page2.show(); just this '{}' this brackets are not required.

Comment: I tried and it's working. Do see that the image button is  touch enabled and try again.

Comment: it is on touch enabled

Comment: can you forward me your project so I could help you